# Powershell how to use the < (redirect)

Tags: powershell, terminal

Something like this will work in `shell`, `cmd`, `bash` and so on, but **NOT** in `powershell`:

```bash
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

Is there a simple way to use this the same way in poweshell?

Comment: Why not use `--execute="source C:\temp\filename.SQL"` to pass file as parameter?

Comment: Have you tried the stop parsing token `--%` ? [about_Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.2#the-stop-parsing-token)

Comment: @vonPryz I copy these commands sometimes from bash scripts and I would like to make them work with minimal effort/changes